# refresh table after ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to refresh my table after ajax success

```js
function deleteUser(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit':id}, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result)
        }
    }); 
    
}
```

```html
<table id="table-demo" style=" border:1px solid #00CCFF!important;" class="table  table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>pass</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>level</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>last login</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $usersQry="select * from admins";
        $usersQryResult=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$usersQry);
        $c=1;
        while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($usersQryResult)){
            echo"
            <tr>
                <td>$c</td>
                <td>$user[user]</td>
                <td>$user[pass]</td>
                <td>$user[email]</td>
                <td>$user[level]</td>
                <td>$user[status]</td>
                <td>$user[lastlogin]</td>
                <td><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='delete'></i></td>
                <td>**<i onclick=\"deleteUser($user[id])\" class='fa fa-trash-o ' title='edit'></i>**</td>                    
            </tr>
            ";
            
            $c++;
        }
        ?>
        
        <!--insert.php -->  
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $idval=$_POST['submit'];
            $query="delete from admins where id=$idval";
            $result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$query) or die("error 100");
            echo mysqli_affected_rows($dbCnn);
            echo "## $idval";
        }
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

after click on delete the user with posted id value to insert.php delete successfuly from admins table of data base. how is it possible refresh table after success of ajax?

Comment: you can do `$(this).parents("tr:first").remove()`

Comment: I think its possible , but if the user was not the first one of the list!!?

Comment: It works for all rows. `parents()` find from current element. **inner to outer** so from inner to outer first `tr` is your current `row`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do

call function as `deleteUser($user[id],this)`

```
function deleteUser(id,thisObj){
           $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'submit':id}, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
            success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            //if success
            $(thisObj).parents("tr:first").remove();
            }
        }); 

}
```

Comment: If delete performs success then he only have to return its response and that row have to get deleted.

Comment: It works for all rows. `parents()` find from current element. **inner to outer** so from inner to outer first `tr` is his current `row`

Comment: I have done it, but it has this error: referenceErro:thisObj is not defined

Comment: Have you pass `this` reference as second parameter?

Comment: is it corect?: onclick=\"deleteUser($user[id],this)\"

Comment: @Hamid except my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to achieve this:

---

1)
You pass the element you've clicked on, and use it in jQuery to find the row to remove from your table:

HTML / PHP

```
// ...
<td><i onclick=\"deleteUser($user[id], this)\" class='fa fa-trash-o ' title='edit'></i></td>
// ...
```

jQuery:

```
function deleteUser(id, element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit':id}, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
        success: function (result) {
            $(element).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    }); 
}
```

This solution is quite simple, and doesn't need too much refactoring from your current code

---

2) Your `insert.php` returns the table once you've already updated the database, and you replace the old table in your HTML

generate_table.php

```
<table id="table-demo" style=" border:1px solid #00CCFF!important;" class="table  table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>pass</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>level</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>last login</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $usersQry="select * from admins";
        $usersQryResult=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$usersQry);
        $c=1;
        while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($usersQryResult)){
            echo"
            <tr>
                <td>$c</td>
                <td>$user[user]</td>
                <td>$user[pass]</td>
                <td>$user[email]</td>
                <td>$user[level]</td>
                <td>$user[status]</td>
                <td>$user[lastlogin]</td>
                <td><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='delete'></i></td>
                <td>**<i onclick=\"deleteUser($user[id])\" class='fa fa-trash-o ' title='edit'></i>**</td>                    
            </tr>
            ";

            $c++;
        }
        ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $idval=$_POST['submit'];
    $query="delete from admins where id=$idval";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbCnn,$query) or die("error 100");
}

include('generate_table.php);
?>
```

HTML / PHP

```
<div id=tableContainer">
    <?php
    include('generate_table.php');
    ?>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function deleteUser(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit':id}, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
        success: function (result) {
            $("#tableContainer").html(result);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This solution requires a bit of refactoring, but you'll be sure that **your table will always reflects the currently registered datas**

Comment: I believe you're talking about the solution 2: `result` will contain the table since I modified you're `insert.php` file to include the `generate_table.php` file in it, which *is* the table

Comment: I have used your second solution. it refreshed my table,but the styles missed.!!!

Answer (score -3):

check out DataTables plugin, he's got some good tools for auto-refresh and other things http://www.datatables.net/

I'd suggest reloading the table after the ajax call to make sure everything stays in synch, which is really easy to do with this plugin

Comment: how reload the table?